# Google Analytics Android Cache Instance without Internet Connection

Tags: android, google-analytics-api

In Google Analytics Android API, if wireless connection is not available when we use the EasyTracker to send the data, what happens to that instance of the data? Will the data be cached? and upload when wireless is available?

Answer (score 0):

From the Google Analytics docs:

> If a user loses network access or quits your app while there are still hits waiting to be dispatched, those hits are persisted in local storage. They will be dispatched the next time your app is running and dispatch is called.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/dispatch

Keep in mind that

> Data must be dispatched and received by 4 a.m. of the following day, in the local timezone of each profile. Any data received later than that will not appear in reports.